# fitting a loess line in R

Tags: r, simulation, predict, loess

I'm having some trouble using `loess()` and `predict()` in R. I have used the following code to simulate data:

```
Overall=0.6
RR=1.1
Noise=0.05

x=seq(from=0.01, to=10, by=0.01) 
logRR=log(RR)
logBeta0=log(Overall)


linear.pred = logBeta0 + (logRR*x) + rnorm(length(x), 0, Noise*sqrt(x))
linear.pred.high = logBeta0 + (logRR*15) + rnorm(length(x), 0, Noise/5)

PoissonRate <- function (x) ifelse(x<=9, exp(linear.pred), exp(linear.pred.high))

xyplot(PoissonRate(x)~x) #the shape of the 'raw' data


loess_fit <- loess(x~PoissonRate(x))
lines(predict(loess_fit), col = "black")
```

Apologies but I can't work out how to attach a picture to show what this looks like!

The last two lines of code end up just adding a random black line half off the graph, although when I have used this command on different (very similar) data before, it has seemed to work fine. What am I missing?! Any help would be great, thanks :)

Comment: You can't use `lines` to add data to a lattice graphics plot. See `lline()`. You are plotting the data back-to-front. If the model is `x~PoissonRate(x)` then you plot `x~PoissonRate(x)` in `xyplot`. In the `llines()` you need to give the `x` and `y` arguments - but you only give output from `predict()`, a vector...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `llines()` (if that is what you meant by `lines()`) outside of the `xyplot` call, at least to my understanding. `?llines` has:

```
Description:

     These functions are intended to replace common low level
     traditional graphics functions, primarily for use in panel
     functions.
```

Hence, one option is to do as it suggests and build your own panel function on the fly. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(pr = PoissonRate(x), x = x)
loess_fit <- loess(pr ~ x, data = dat)

xyplot(PoissonRate(x) ~ x,
  panel = function(x, y, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    llines(dat$x, predict(loess_fit), col.line = "red")
  })
```

which produces:

[image]

In general, I would probably do this a different way - I would generate the data outside the formula. The I would `predict` for new data locations spread evenly and in order over the range of `x`. That way, even if the input data are not in increasing order in `x` you get sensible predictions you can use for a line plot. E.g.

```
## following on from the above
pred <- with(dat, data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100)))
pred <- transform(pred, pr = predict(loess_fit, newdata = x))

xyplot(PoissonRate(x) ~ x,
  panel = function(x, y, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    with(pred, llines(x, pr, col.line = "red"))
  })
```